# Have a Zend_Filter that has access to the database

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to have a Zend_Filter that has access to the database, for example for transforming a city name into a numeric city id?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can get your database like this `$adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but when I put that filter into a form element and try to render that form, the system try to execute the filter method with a null value, so all the query fall into errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are validators that use the db like Db_RecordExists and Db_NoRecordExists. Look at the code of those and write your own Filter using the same approach.

Basically you just have to extend the Filter class and implement your own filter, what you do in there, is entirely up to you. In the end you just have to return the filtered value.